# Where can I learn more about the PowerPoint 2010 file format?

Tags: powerpoint, openxml, drawingml, presentationml

Where can I find the PowerPoint file format definition, like the header/XML/directory structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerPoint 2010 uses three *primary* markup languages - PresentationML, DrawingML and PowerPoint 2010 Extentions. The first two are part of [ISO/IEC 29500:2008](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_tc_browse.htm?commid=45374) specs, the last one isn't.

But in all cases with and above PowerPoint 2007, the document structure (i.e. what XML and other files go where in a .pptx and how they relate) is an implementation of the [Open Packaging Convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Packaging_Convention). For details, go to the section **PresentationML document structure** of the [Open XML Explained](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=6f264d0b-23e8-43fe-9f82-9ab627e5eaa3&displaylang=en) e-book. For 2010-specific extensions, this document lists them: [PowerPoint Extensions to the Office Open XML File Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd926741.aspx).